# i want to fix an error or repair the LAMP php server installation on AWS ec2 Linux instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, lamp

am having issues with access my phpMyadmin amazon aws. all was working fine but when i installed ssl certificate i get this problem.

the database is working fine but i cannot access the phpmyadmin to add or modify a table.

i get the below error when i type in mywebsite/PhpMyAdmin

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Unable to find template "login/header.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/templates).

can any one help. am using LAMP on AWS linux Ec2 instance

i cannot access phpmyadmin on aws linux instance. before installing ssl on my domain all was ok but now i get this error whenever i try to access phpmyadmin.
wheneve i type mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin i get the below error

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Unable to find template "login/header.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/templates).